# How to detect unsafe platforms?

Tags: angry-video-game-nerd-adventures

In [Angry Video Game Nerd Adventures](http://store.steampowered.com/app/237740) some platforms fall down when stepped on. It seems that falling ground (highlighted in blue on the left) doesn't look any different from normal, safe platforms (on the right). Is there visual difference?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

The whole confusion of the falling and not falling platforms is a design choice. AVGN Adventures is kind of a tribute to old extremely difficult NES games that didn't hold your hand and give you information and were just generally unfair. See Ghosts and Goblins, Castlevania, Megaman, etc. So no there is no way to determine what platforms will fall and which ones do not, trial and error is the only way to figure out what to avoid.

Comment: Generally the game makes the rules extremely clear and you always know which objects cause damage. From [Destructoid review](https://www.destructoid.com/review-angry-video-game-nerd-adventures-262392.phtml): "Every obstacle in the game operates on very simple patterns that can be observed from a distance before being approached. Spikes that emerge from the floor? Fire pillars or laser turrets that trigger at regular intervals? Maces that circle the bricks they are chained to? Just count the seconds and time your progress. Your mistakes are entirely your own."

Comment: Still though this game is a tribute to the older style of video games which weren't so nice to you. The AVGN game is the kind of game that is meant to make you angry at playing it, hence it being an **Angry** Video Game Nerd game.